# Unity Version X86 re dead, but the X86_64 Bits is alive now.... which version?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Android Version X86 re dead, but the X86_64 Bits is alive now, which version? `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64`
anybody can see the **x86_64** in Unity Version after 2017.x?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what options you should choose to build an Android app for the Google Play store with Unity?

Comment: Yes, the version of Unity to export for x86_64 do Huawei, GooglePlay & IOS, Tizen, Samsung etc...

Comment: The options in your screen shot are what we use for our games. Unity has said they are removing X86 support for Android. https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/successful-unity-aab-build-not-compliant-with-the-google-play-64-bit-requirement.729035/):

> x86 is used by less than 0.4% of all Android devices, so it shouldn't
>   have any real impact.
>
> You may probably already noticed but in 2019.2 x86 target is marked as
>   deprecated, in 2019.3 it will be removed completely.

Unity doesn't support **x86_64** for Android.